# Find the set of points at which the series is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $f$ be defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Find the set of points at which $f$ is holomorphic, where
\begin{align*}
&f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{(5n)^n} \mbox{ for every $z$ for which} \sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{(5n)^n} \mbox{ converges,} \\& f(z)=0 \mbox{ for every $z$ for which} \sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n}}{(5n)^n} \mbox{ does not converge.}
\end{align*}
I know that $f$ is holomorphic everywhere if the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, but how do I apply that to a series? I tried setting $z=x+iy$ and then calculating the partial derivatives, but that seems to lead to nowhere in particular. Would appreciate any help I can get thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the series $g(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{(5n)^n}$ is an entire function by Hadamard's formula since
$$\lim a_n^{1/n}=\lim\frac1{5n}=0$$
Hence $f(z)=g(z^2)$ is also an entire function.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot man